# How can we add two events on a same element in Framerjs?

Tags: framerjs

I am trying to make an accordion list view. When I click the parent folder list item, I want my parent list to be expanded. On clicking again, the list should collapse.

Comment: And what have you done so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh Pucket made an example available in the FB group that should help you get started:

http://share.framerjs.com/ff51agq8rx06/

Basically, you need arrays and you always check on other elements if they need to be updated ( either moved / expanded or collapsed )

hope this helps!